# Passing custom Python objects to nosetests

Tags: python, testing, automation, nose, nosetests

I am attempting to re-organize our test libraries for automation and nose seems really promising.  My question is, what is the best strategy for passing Python objects into nose tests?

Our tests are organized in a testlib with a bunch of modules that exercise different types of request operations.  Something like this:

```
testlib
\-testmoda
\-testmodb
\-testmodc
```

In some cases the test modules (i.e. testmoda) is nothing but test_something(), test_something2() functions while in some cases we have a TestModB class in testmob with the test_anotherthing1(), test_anotherthing2() functions.  The cool thing is that nose easily finds both.

Most of those test functions are request factory stuff that can easily share a single connection to our server farm.  Thus we do a lot of test_something1(cnn), TestModB.test_anotherthing2(cnn), etc.

Currently we don't use nose, instead we have a hodge-podge of homegrown driver scripts with hard-coded lists of tests to execute.  Each of those driver scripts creates its own connection object.  Maintaining those scripts and the connection minutia is painful.

I'd like to take free advantage of nose's beautiful discovery functionality, passing in a connection object of my choosing.

Thanks in advance!

Rob

P.S. The connection objects are not pickle-able.  :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you use a factory create the connections, then have the functions `test_something1()` (taking no arguments) use the factory to get a connection?

Comment: That's one approach I've considered, although each call to the factory currently creates a new unique connection.  Ideally I'd like to construct a single connection object, then hand it over to nose.

Comment: If you want the factory to return a common (shared) connection, it's easy to make it so.

Comment: @Matt - Awesome.  Using the structure I noted in the desciption, what do you recommend?  Within the module space is easy enough to do, but how do I share a single global connection to all testlib modules when firing off nosetests.exe ?  I'm still a Python newbie and missing something basic here.

Comment: @Matt - All examples I have seen to date rely upon passing a pickled object (which does not make sense in this case for an open socket connection), or passing configuration details to the test and having the test function (or test class) create a new object and run with it.  Ideally I'd like to pass in an object of my choosing, or globally share that object everywhere.

Comment: @Rob You could possibly use fixtures - fixtures are basically set up/tear down code that runs before and after tests. Nose lets you create package level fixtures, so you could set up your single instance in the package set up, then all tests within the scope of the package will run, then the package tear down will run.

Comment: @Rob Can you proxy the connection? Then you wouldn't need to pickle it - the tests talk to the proxy, the proxy either gets a real connection or a test connection - the test fixture set-up can switch the proxy into "test" mode.

Comment: @Rob At the end of the day you probably can't get away without making architectural changes, but the positive spin on that is the changes you make are all about reducing coupling, which can help improve your overall system design. (If you've already been doing testing, your system is hopefully not too intertangled anyway.)

Comment: @Matt Thank you very much for the tip about package level fixture --- that should suffice as a work-around.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, there is no easy way to simply pass custom objects to Nose.

However, as Matt pointed out there are some viable workarounds to achieve similar results.

Basically, do this:

1. Setup a data dictionary as a package level global
2. Add custom objects to that dictionary
3. Create some factory functions to return those custom objects or create new ones if they're present/suitable
4. Refactor the existing testlib\testmod* modules to use the factory